# Ubuntu 10.10 and Windows 7 (TrueCrypt) Multi-boot Problems

Tags: ubuntu, windows-7, truecrypt, boot

I have now been searching days for a solution but have found nothing.

I have Ubuntu 10.10 and Windows 7 with TrueCrypt as a multi-boot. It was working fine for a few weeks until I needed to reinstall Ubuntu. If I have the boot flag on the partition where Windows 7 is install (This is where the boot flags was when working before.), it boots fine in to Windows 7 but when pressing Esc it can't find grub2. If I have the boot flag on the partition where Ubuntu is install, it boots fine in to Ubuntu (by pressing Esc or typing the password) but unable to access Windows.

I have tried reinstalling TrueCrypt Boot loader and repairing the header but it have no affect.

My Partitions:

- sda1 - Windows 7 Recovery (GRUB2)
- sda2 - Windows 7 (TrueCrypt Boot Loader)
- sda3 - Ubuntu 10.10 (/)
- sda4 - Extended
- sda5 - Swap
- sda6 - Ubuntu (/home)

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks
Sam

Answer (score 1):

A re-crypt of the partition might help. It can take a lot of time, but, it case fix it.

Usually, windows partition is active but, when you re-installed ubuntu where did you installed the bootloader? What was your choice?

I'll check on another mixed env. laptop what partition is active. BBL

Comment: the boot flag on sda1 atm so I can use Ubuntu, I only use Windows for work and I'm currently off. I installed the bootloader in sda1